# NSString is empty with length = 1?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, string, string-length

I have encountered a really odd behavior:

```
NSLog(@"substring: '%@'\t- length: %d",substring,substring.length);
```

returns

```
substring: '‍'  - length: 1
```

The substring variable is a NSString object.

Can someone please explain what is going on...

**EDIT :: SOLVED**

As Amy answered:

> It's printing an invisible character.:
>   ‍
>
> ZERO WIDTH JOINER Unicode: U+200D, UTF-8: E2 80 8D

```
if ([substring isEqualToString:@"\u200d"]) {
    NSLog(@"It is a ZERO WIDTH JOINER...");
}
```

And thanks to Phillip for the tip.

Comment: What is in `substring`? Could it be a zero width character? (e.g. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm )

Comment: What happens if you use `NSLog(@"Character value: %d", [substring characterAtIndex:0]);`?

Comment: Actually, it'll return `(nil)` if your array is with length 0, not `''`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's printing an invisible character.:

‍
ZERO WIDTH JOINER
Unicode: U+200D, UTF-8: E2 80 8D

Answer (score 1):

What about invisible space? You should check your substring for U+200B symbol, or take a look here http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html

Answer (score 0):

Might be some kind of whitespace. If you want to ignore whitespace, you can try:

```
string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I have tryed this before posting the question and it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I had to trim using the following to get rid of some extra invisibles.

```
[[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet]
```